# Setting up Stage environment (Caching) for APIGateway using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have setup `APIGateway` using `CloudFormation` which has exposed one method as `/customers/{customerId}`. The method calls `dynamodb` service rather using any lambda and sends back `HTTP 200` with an empty object if mapping is missing or a `customer` object with `HTTP 200`.

Now, I want to setup caching for my `prod` stage. I have an existing api which i created using the AWS APIGateway Web UI and created the prod stage. I want to replicate those properties in CF. Here is what i have in my old api

**Cache Settings**

Cache Status: AVAILABLE

Cache Capacity: 0.5GB

Cache time-to-live (TTL): 300

**Per-key cache invalidation**

Require authorization: checked
Handle unauthorized requests: Ignore cache control header; Add a warning in response header

**Default Method Throttling**

Enable Throttling: checked

Rate: 1000

Burst: 200

I tried setting up the first part (cache settings) like this but it didn't result in desired prod stage settings as i was expecting. How can i acheive desired above output using CloudFormation?

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters":{
        "EnvType": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "test",
            "AllowedValues": ["test", "prod"],
            "Description": "Select what stage need to be created"
        }
    },
    "Conditions":{
        "CreateProdStage" : {"Fn::Equals": [{"Ref":"EnvType"}, "prod"]},
        "CreateTestStage" : {"Fn::Equals": [{"Ref":"EnvType"}, "test"]}
    },
    "Resources": {
        "MyAPI": {
            ...
        },
        "MyAPIResource": {
            ...
        },
        "GetMethod":{
            ...
        },
        "ApiDeployment":{
            "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
            "Properties":{
                "RestApiId":{"Ref":"MyAPI"}
            },
            "DependsOn":["GetMethod"]
        },
        "TestStage" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
            "Condition":"CreateTestStage",
            "Properties" : {
                "DeploymentId" : {"Ref":"ApiDeployment"},
                "Description" : "Test Stage",
                "RestApiId" : {"Ref":"MyAPI"},
                "StageName" : "test"
            }
        },
        "ProdStage" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
            "Condition":"CreateProdStage",
            "Properties" : {
                "DeploymentId" : {"Ref":"ApiDeployment"},
                "Description" : "Prod Stage",
                "RestApiId" : {"Ref":"MyAPI"},
                "StageName" : "prod",
                "MethodSettings":[{
                    "CachingEnabled":true,
                    "HttpMethod":"*",
                    "ResourcePath":"/*",
                    "CacheTtlInSeconds":300,
                    "ThrottlingBurstLimit" : 2000,
                    "ThrottlingRateLimit" : 1000

                }]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly was different in the resulting CloudFormation-based API?

Comment: The resulting stack doesn't have `Cache Status` as `Checked`, No settings for `CacheCapacity` and `Cache time-to-live`. Also, I can't figure otu how to setup `Per-Key cache invalidation`

Comment: It looks like you are missing the CacheCluster definition within the stage definition (in addition to the method settings). As for the per-key invalidation, I there doesn't seem to be an option for that in cloudformation.

Comment: @EmAe, did you ever figure out how how to do this?

Comment: Nope. I guess it's not currently supported by CF

Comment: There is a property called `CacheClusterSize` - not sure if it refers to Cache Capacity but it look like so.

Answer (score 2):

In the properties of each stage you need to set `"CacheClusterEnabled": true`, i.e.:

```
"TestStage" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
        "Condition":"CreateTestStage",
        "Properties" : {
            "DeploymentId" : {"Ref":"ApiDeployment"},
            "Description" : "Test Stage",
            "RestApiId" : {"Ref":"MyAPI"},
            "StageName" : "test",
            "CacheClusterEnabled": "true"
        }
    },
```

Here are the docs:
API Gateway Stage (CacheClusterEnabled):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-stage.html#cfn-apigateway-stage-cacheclusterenabled

API Gateway MethodSetting (note is says caching must be enabled on the stage first):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-stage-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-stage-methodsetting-cachingenabled